# Does the box API require case-sensitive booleans?

Tags: box-api

I'm having some issues with the box.com developer API, and it seems that this is due to the API requiring lower-case booleans in request parameters.

When I make a call to say, delete a folder, the URI my framework is generating looks like this:

(DELETE) https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/1234?recursive=True

This doesn't work, and the API throws an error. However, if I manually set the URI to this:

(DELETE) https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/1234?recursive=true

Everything seems to work just fine. I'd like to confirm that this is indeed the behavior, and if it is, I'd like to request box fix their API!

Comment: Why should Box "fix" their API? In most languages (though not Python) boolean literals are lowercased, not title cased, and [the expected input case is clearly documented](http://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-delete-a-folder).

Answer (score 0):

Currently booleans in URL query parameters must be lowercased.